# XML attributes order in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, code-formatting

I'm facing problem with keeping proper order of XML attributes in Android Studio. As you can see below, the `style` attribute is between `layout_*` attributes, but I want it to be ordered by name (like in Eclipse). I'm using standard Intellij code formatter and the Android Studio gives users ability to set your own rules regarding XML ordering. The settings are located in `Code Style -> XML -> Arrangement`, but it seems not to work or I'm using it wrong. Any ideas how to order XML attributes by name using default code formatter?

```
<TestView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    style="@style/BackgroundLight"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</TestView>
```

Comment: Note that unless there is a bug in the layout preview in Android Studio, then for ConstraintLayouts, the layout is dependent on the order of attributes. For instance if I put layout_height and layout_width after constraintX_toYof, then I get a different result than if I don't.

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Finally got it.

1. Choose `File > Settings > Code Style > XML > Set from > Predefined Style > Android`
2. Set `File > Settings > Editor > Formatting > Show "Reformat Code" dialog`
3. Run formatting on a XML file (`CTRL+ALT+L` by default)
4. You will see a popup window, set the `Rearrange entries` flag
5. Disable `Reformat Code` dialog in the settings

This way every XML file formatting will set the attributes in a proper order.

Edit:
Starting with Android Studio 0.2.6 release the XML Android style formatting is set by default, but you still have to set the `Rearrange Entries` flag manually.

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio026released

> Automatically apply the Android XML code style if a code style hasn't
>   already been customized. This will make it possible to automatically
>   order XML attributes (check the "Rearrange Entries" checkbox in the
>   "Code > Reformat Code..." dialog.)

Comment: It rearranges attributes, but it doesn't delete empty lines between them

Comment: for ubuntu its CTRL+Shift+ALT+L

Comment: The keyboard shortcut may vary depending on platform and configuration. To check or change it go to Settings -> Keymap -> Reformat Code

Comment: This answer is outdated, 2nd number changed. Use Ctrl + Alt + Shift + L.

Answer (score 29):

UPDATE: the method I described below is an official way to fix this known issue, see: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases

After updating to the newest `Android Studio v3.4.2` I found that it doesn't format XML code properly anymore. For instance, `attributes ordering didn't work in layouts`. It did indentation and namespaces ordering only.

I don't know the reason why it was broken after an update but was lucky to fix this:

1. Go to `Settings` (`CMD` `+` `,` ) on Mac.
2. Type `format` in Search box and click on `Editor -> XML` setting.
3. Click on the `Android` tab and make the same settings here as it's on a picture:

> [image: Android tab in XML formatting Setting]
>     Settings on a picture quite normal, but of course you can tune this tab setting up to you.

4. Go to the `Arrangement` tab and you will see something like this:

> [image: Arrangement tab in XML formattings Setting]
>     The reason why attributes are not getting sorted - sorting rules are empty.

5. To fix this:

   1. Choose `Scheme` and play with `Default IDE` and `Project` options. Switching between them may help.
   2. Or choose `Scheme` which suites your needs and then click on `Set from...` blue text in right upper corner `-> Predefined Style -> Android`. You will see restored rules in the window:

> [image: Finally you will see restored rules here]
>     I also chose `Force rearrange - Always`

To save result – click `Apply`.

Also you can click on a gear icon near `Scheme` and copy settings or even restore defaults.

P.S. To me standard rules are comfortable, but it can be customized further. Here is an article which may help doing this: https://medium.com/@VeraKern/formatting-xml-layout-files-for-android-47aec62722fc

Answer (score 10):

Go to your layout XML 
Try **Ctrl + alt + shift + L** then find checkbox label is **Rearrange code** and checked its.

Answer (score 5):

To delete empty lines between them:

Preferences > Code Style > XML > Other > Keep blank lines: 0

And then just reformat your XML files.

Comment: works for me very good. There are blank lines between widgets but not inside widget code.

Comment: How to format xml files in android studio? ctrl+alt+L doesn't work for me in mac

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for IntelliJ which might do what you're after...

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&pluginId=6546

Comment: I'm using this plugin to format Java source code but it doesn't format  XML files.

Answer (score 0):

File > Settings > Editor > XML > Arrangement Select Scheme and choose Default