# How to "Stack" code in Android Studio's Editor?

Tags: android, ide

I've decided to dive into Android Development following Google's Udacity Course, till' now everything's fine except there's a slight thing that's annoying me.

As you can see in this the codes are on top of each other (Organized by me and I want it this way).

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivityFragment">
```

But by default AS insists to organize it like this:

```
android:name="com.example.saad.sunshine.app.MainActivityFragment"
tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Is there a way to change the default behaviour of Android studio to do what I want? Like an option in the settings?

Comment: You should read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206019/xml-attributes-order-in-android-studio

Comment: @user1774537 That solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can change the appearance of the XML files:

**Settings** >> **Code Style** >> **XML**

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I've tried changing a couple of settings there but I couldn't find the one I'm looking for and honestly I didn't dive deeper since I'm not that experienced with Android Studio and don't wanna break things off. So if you told me the exact setting it would be nice.

Comment: I saw that the other solution helped you more. Next time I will be more specific.