# XML attributes arrangement in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

[I like to arrange my XML files similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206019/xml-attributes-order-in-android-studio)

But I'd like to add an ordering like this:

1. View id
2. Style
3. Layout width and layout heigt
4. Other `layout_` attributes, sorted alphabetically
5. Remaining attributes, sorted alphabetically

Example:

```
<Button
    android:id="@id/button_accept"
    style="@style/ButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:text="@string/button_skip_sign_in"
    android:textColor="@color/bluish_gray" />
```

I had a look at `Editor -> Code Style -> XML -> Arrangement`, but the only thing I could do was order every attribute alphabetically. [This documentation from IntelliJ couldn't help me](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/code-style-xml.html#d48088e1728) I'm still not sure what the `namespace` is supposed to do.

Maybe someone here understands it better? The UI gave me the impression, that the order of the matching rules is, what the order of the attributes should be. But somehow it doesn't change or do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm feeling stupid now, but I figured out my mistake: name of the attribute in question needs to start with `android:`.

Result:
[image: Screenshot of Android Studio XML arrangement]

Comment: Wow, that helps me a lot.