# Auto Arrangement Of Attributes in Android XML Files

Tags: xml, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'd like to automatically arrange attributes of XML as follows:

1. Layout width and layout height
2. All other attributes, sorted alphabetically
3. **And *"id"* attribute is always *at the end***

I need to put **"id"** attribute to the end of XML attributes list. In my scheme, **"id"** is sorted with other attributes in alphabetical order.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089102/xml-attributes-arrangement-in-android-studio?rq=1

Comment: Yes, there is no answer for my question...