# Reformat code /ctrl + alt + l/ doesn't work or it's working wrong. How to fix it?

Tags: android, xml, keyboard-shortcuts

I wrote this code:

```
<LinearLayout >
    <View/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText />
        <EditText/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <View />
</LinearLayout>
```

Use ctrl + alt + l:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <EditText />
    <EditText />
</LinearLayout>
<View/>
<View />
```

In fact, work in this order.

```
<LinearLayout >
    <View/>
    <LinearLayout>
        <EditText />
        <EditText />
    </LinearLayout >
    <View />
</LinearLayout >
```

How to fix? I used to this keyboard shortcut before. But now it's working wrong.

Comment: Hi! What editor and version are you using?

Comment: @Enselic android studio, gradle plugin version 3.5.0, gradle version 5.4.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XML attributes order in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206019/xml-attributes-order-in-android-studio)

Comment: @PoyyamozhiRamakrishnan cool thank you :3 it's working