# XML's arrangement android

Tags: android, xml

When I use Shift+Alt+L I get XML arrangement like here. How can I fix it? Which rule I need to add to Setting/Editor/XML/Arrangement?
I tried to do like here [XML attributes order in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18206019/xml-attributes-order-in-android-studio).
But it doesn't help.

[image: What I have]

I want like here:

[image: What I want]

Comment: Please show what you get and what you want.

Comment: I added link for as I have now to question, and I want like here [2] (https://www.yandex.ru/images/search?from=tabbar&text=xml%20android&pos=5&img_url=http%3A%2F%2Fmiro.medium.com%2Fmax%2F1400%2F1*VP7S9GzVirJcqTtxo9mEZQ.png&rpt=simage&lr=2) for example. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you checked "Align attributes" which is **not** enabled by default.

See the mouse cursor on the screenshot.

[image: Screenshot]